# Webpack does not package Angular2 component styles background url

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a HomeComponent which loads a home.css through

```
styleUrls: ['home.css']
```

the home.css

```
.home {
    background: url('../../img/home.png') no-repeat;
}
```

(has a valid path)

Webpack does not bundle the image in the assets directory with npm run build nor loads it in dev mode with npm start.

webpack.common.js (from this [official Angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.ts$/,
                 loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-        loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                 loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

I also tried using npm install resolve-url which helped to build te dist folder files but not the live dev using npm start (from the tutorial)

```
...
//instead of the 'raw' loader            
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loaders: ['style','css?sourceMap', 'resolve-url']
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have configured the `angular2-template-loader` correctly? There seem to be some issues with the version you posted above (some whitespaces in the loader name). But I assume this resulted from pasting your source to stackoverflow and your source doesn't look like this.

What looks differently to the sample project is the way you are referencing your css file in the `styleUrls` array.

Could you try to reference the files as relative paths like `styleUrls: ['./home.css']` instead of `styleUrls: ['home.css']`? This could affect how the `angular2-template-loader` tries to resolve the files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the dev environment work and generate the images for the production dist folder by simply changing the css 'raw' loader in webpack.common.js for

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loaders: ['to-string', 'style', 'css?sourceMap']
        }
```

and installing [npm to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-string-loader).

I did not need to use any resolve-url loaders in this case.